# Location Regex and ProxyPass Regex for NGINX conf

Tags: regex, nginx, config, nginx-reverse-proxy

Wondering if there is a way to configure my nginx.conf file to use a regex to match my proxy url's in the location block and then also use a regex for the proxypass url.  My setup current works fine when I have a static path, but I'd like to expand that to use 2 or more sort of like follows.  The original is:

```
location  /pacs-1/  {

        auth_request /auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        proxy_buffering off;
        rewrite /pacs-1/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://pacs-1:8042;
        proxy_redirect  http://pacs-1:8042/ /;
```

and I'd like to do something like the following, which clearly does not work (i.e. (?:pacs-butterfly|pacs-1|pacs-2)).  For the proxy pass I need to use whatever path matched from the location block for the proxy rewrite and the proxy pass / redirects.  Not sure that there is a way to do that.

```
location  /(pacs-butterfly|pacs-1|pacs-2)/ {  #match any of those in ()

. . . not sure how to code what I show below.

        auth_request /auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        proxy_buffering off;
        rewrite /(?:pacs-butterfly|pacs-1|pacs-2)/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://(?:pacs-butterfly|pacs-1|pacs-2):8042;
        proxy_redirect  http://(?:pacs-butterfly|pacs-1|pacs-2):8042/ /;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing the `~` for Regex matching.  Parentheses can be added to capture variables in `$n` format, and `$request_uri` is also available:

```
location ~ ^/(pacs-butterfly|pacs-1|pacs-2)(/.*) {
  default_type text/plain;
  return 200 "
    $1
    $2
    $request_uri
    $args
  ";
}
```

```
$ curl "https://example.com/pacs-1/foo/bar?name=value&foo=bar"

    pacs-1
    /foo/bar
    /pacs-1/foo/bar?name=value&foo=bar
    name=value&foo=bar
```

Comment: I'll look into that.  I take it I can use the variables in my proxy pass and redirect and the rewrite ?

Comment: `rewrite` directives can also be standalone, outside of `location` blocks.

Comment: I tried that and it looks like it matches the location, but rewrite and pass fails:          not sure what I would substitute for rewrite /pacs-1/(.*) /$1 break; abd and for proxy_pass http://pacs-1:8042;.  If I just substitute $1 for pacs-1 it is empty, and I also tried using set $pacs $1; which saves it, but the rewrite still does not work.  I basically want to strip off the match, but then proxy pass to http://{match}:8042

Comment: My original setup works.  the pacs-1, etc. is a Docker Container server, so http://{match}:8042 makes the request to the server in the Container, which is otherwise isolated.  The auth_request /auth; performs some authorization to allow the pass.